# Button image not visible

Tags: image, button, windows-8

I'm trying to create a Windows 8.1 store app, and I need to add a button to it.
The button should display an image.

- I add the image to the assembly in Solution Exploreras Artwork/Pencil.png
- I add the button to the UI
- Using the property editor for the button, I select Foreground image.
- The designer shows a list of available images from the assembly, I choose the image.
- The designer shows the selected image (partially).
- The button remains blank.

I tryied playing around with different content types (of the image), as Content, Embedded resource, Do not copy, Copy if newer.

The image is not visible either at design or run time.

I found tons of articles from 2005 to 2012 about this problem in WPF. Tryed to change the image source (although I think the designer should set it correctly):

- Pencil.png
- Artwork/Pencil.png
- pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Pencil.png
- pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Artwork/Pencil.png
- pack://application:,,,/Pencil.png
- pack://application:,,,/Artwork/Pencil.png

Any ideas?

To make the environment clear:

- Visual Studio 2013 Update 2
- Project type: Visual C#/Store Apps/Windows Apps/Blank App
- Target: Windows 8.1

Comment: plz read how to ask ques/ans which part should go to ans/comment/ or edit in the qiestion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the correct combination (to display an image on a Windows 8 app button) is:

- set it as backbround image (as opposed to foreground)
- set the file to be "PRIResource" (as opposed to "Embedded resource")
- use the designer to specify the image (which will generate a reference like this "Artwork/Pencil.png")

:-(
It works design-time, but it does not work runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works both design-time and runtime:

- set it as backbround image (as opposed to foreground)
- set the file to be "Content", "Copy if newer"
- use the designer to specify the image (which will generate a reference like this "Artwork/Pencil.png")